# Should I sacrifice performance over readability

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a django rest service. Me and my colleague are currently in an argument about django models. We have a model named `Report` which contains field/fields about location (longitude, latitude, address, city, postal code).

Does it make sense that I want to make location a separate model? Other models may also use this location model. Here is what I mean:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()


class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    location = models.OneToOneField(Location)
```

I know that for every query on report there has to be another query on location, but I think it's worth it, because it looks much more clean to me and other models can also use this `Location` model, without copying fields.

Comment: It is ok. Just use `select_related` or `prefetch_related` when you do query with related models

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your question yourself! If you want to reuse the `Location` model it is more then ok to put it in a separate model!